# How do you reduce a linear congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve a linear congruence and I don't understand how some of them are reduced.  For example, How does $105k \equiv -32 \pmod{11}\,$ reduce to $6k \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$?

Comment: Do you know that $105 \equiv 6 \pmod{11}$ and $-32 \equiv 1\pmod{11}$?

Comment: Just reduce all coefficients modulo 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\rm\ \ mod\ \color{#C00}{11}\!:\ \ 105&\rm \equiv&\rm 6\quad\ \ \  and\ \  &{-}32\!\!& &\equiv& 1\\
\rm by\quad  105&-&6 = 9\!\cdot\!\color{#C00}{11},  &{-}32\!\!& &-&1 = 3\!\cdot\!\color{#C00}{11}\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for all $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have $(m\times k) \equiv 0\ \pmod{m}$ and that for any $k,j,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ the following holds - if $k \equiv j\ \pmod{m}$ and $p \equiv q\ \pmod{m}$, than $k+p \equiv j+q\ \pmod{m}$. Needless to say - this does not depend on $m$.